# how to write this query in codeigniter, i send my id to the model, but this query must be writen good in model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT hapnin 
FROM test.user_favourites, test.happenings t 
WHERE user_id = $id 
AND  t.id = happening_id
```

I want to re-write it in a codeiniger model. Please if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure your query is Okay? Try this hope it works.

```
$this->db->select('hapnin')->from('user_favourites, happenings t')->where("user_id = $id AND t.id = happening_id", false)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$this->db->select('hapnin')
         ->from('user_favourites, happenings t')
         ->where("user_id = $id")
         ->where("t.id = happening_id")
         ->get()
         ->result();
```